# Javascript prompt not expanding on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I have an iPad running iOS6.

The javascript prompt I'm creating looks fine on computers in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari - meaning that as lines are added the prompt expands so you can see all the information.  When I view the prompt in Safari or Chrome on the iPad the prompt doesn't expand at all and I have to scroll in this tiny window to see all the information.

How can I expand the prompt in iOS?

The javascript that's creating the prompt looks something like this:

```
for (var i = (currentDealer + 1); i < players.length; i++) {
        var bid = prompt(currentBids + "\r\nTotal Bid so far: " + bidForRound + "\r\n\r\nEnter " + players[i].name + "'s Bid: ");
        bidForRound = bidForRound + parseInt(bid);
        players[i].bid = bid;
        currentBids = currentBids + players[i].name + " bid " + players[i].bid + "\r\n";
}
```

As you can see this will add more lines to it as more players enter their bids.

Comment: Not sure what HTML you need.  The code example of how the prompt is created is right there.

Comment: Oh, I did not even notice you actual meant `prompt` which is native and not controllable and that I would not suggest you use at all

Answer (score 0):

You can't, browsers don't let you control the appearance of the prompt at all.

What you can do is replace the prompt with your own, custom, HTML + Js prompt - but it will never be synchronous as the native prompt.